# Extract basenames of multiple files from one path

Tags: java, file, path, extract, filenames

#### Hello programmers!

I have some issue related with the filepath in Java.

Take a look at this path (in the real filepath there's **no** "{}" brackets, and **NULL** is *real* null mark):

```
\\server\directory\64956012.TIF{NULL}64956014.TIF{NULL}64956016.TIF{NULL}64956018.TIF%
```

#### The question is:

is there some easy way to extract these filenames using i.e. **Apache Commons**?
I don't need whole path (prefix) - I need only **filenames**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where the names come from? can you add your code please?

Comment: So you need to get from the above `String` the names like: `64956012.TIF`, `64956014.TIF` etc? And what real null mark means?

Comment: Yes I need String names like you've mentioned.
Real null means it's ASCII null sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the format is always the same have a first part with path info and ending with %.

```
String s1 = "\\\\serverdirectory\\64956012.TIF\u000064956014.TIF\u000064956016.TIF\u000064956018.TIF%";
String s2 = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, s1.length() - 1);
String[] splitted = s2.split("\u0000");
for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++)
    System.out.println(splitted[i]);
```

s2 contains only the list of filenames separated by the null byte (\u0000).
The output of this code is:

```
64956012.TIF
64956014.TIF
64956016.TIF
64956018.TIF
```